# ssh Exception in Java: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, ssh, netbeans, server

I want to run a script with ssh using Java but there is always an Exception: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

this is my code

```java
public class RemoteScriptExec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            Session session;  

            // String host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname", System.getProperty("user.name") + //"@localhost");
            // String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
            //host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

            session = jsch.getSession("","197.31.73.196", 22); 
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

            session.setPassword("");

            session.connect();

            if (session.isConnected()){
                System.out.println("ok");
            } else {
                System.out.println("failed");
            }

            ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

            channelExec.setCommand("sh myscript.sh Rajesh");
            channelExec.connect();
            // by the executing command, from the remote side.
            InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            int exitStatus = channelExec.getExitStatus();
            if (exitStatus > 0) {
                System.out.println("Remote script exec error! " + exitStatus);
            }
            //Disconnect the Session
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Ncib, please edit your question to have [only English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: Does a regular `ssh 197.31.73.196` command work?

Comment: Update your question to show the stack trace, and identify the line in your code which is failing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it was a problem of internet connection

Comment: The problem was that nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. 197.31.73.196 is not an Internet address.